# iTunes Connect Promo Codes & App Updates

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

We have recently released version 1.0.0 of our application and have sent out numerous promo codes in the past couple of days. I was just wondering whether they will still be valid for the 1.0.1 update which we have just submitted?

Comment: This question doesn't belong to SO

Comment: Agreed — but it's a very old question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes.

Promo codes apply to your app no matter the version (only the version currently available on the store), and no matter the price (even if it's free a code should work.)

Comment: Just had this confirmed by the iTunes Connect Support. The said: "Promotional codes are valid for four weeks from the time they are generated in iTunes Connect. They will work for any version released in the time they are valid."

Answer (score 2):

Here is the text from the apple promotional website:

> Select an application and enter the number of codes you are requesting. You are given 50 codes for each version of an application. They are for non-commercial use and will expire four weeks after they are requested. These codes can only be used in the U.S. iTunes Store.

From this text, it is clear that you can issue brand new codes for new versions of your app.  It is not clear whether your codes from 1.0.0 will still be valid for the 1.0.1 version of your app.  I would think that they would still be valid, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Yeah I read that, not really too clear! Hoping someone who has experience can let us know.