# redeem code for app in iTunes Store, still valid when new version accepted?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

i've recently uploaded my first app on iTunes Store, it's been accepted and now it's on-line.

i've downloaded some promo code (redeem) and eMailed away to let them download it free and try it.

but now i saw there was a (little) error in my app and wanted to submit a new corrected version.

my question is: what happen if apple accepts my new version, will the redeem code still work, is someone has not used it before?
i know that developer can ask 50 redeem for every version of an app, so i guess that they are linked just to that version...

has someone here an experience about that?

thanks,
luca

Comment: This question doesn't belong to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promo codes are still valid (but only for the rest of the 28-day-period after they've been requested) after the update is live. See [iTunes Connect Promo Codes & App Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988908/itunes-connect-promo-codes-app-updates).

Comment: tks, i had lost that answer...

Comment: Yup, never had a problem with this.